# Django - How can i assign a value to a object using a formset but in a view

Tags: django, django-forms

(Sorry for my bad english)
I need to add a value to a object field, that i'm excluding from the formset. i like to auto assign this in a view. (i can't modify the model to add a def save method and make it there because is a third party app model)

This is the model

```
class Tax(models.Model):
    """A tax (type+amount) for a specific Receipt."""

    tax_type = models.ForeignKey(
        TaxType,
        verbose_name=_('tax type'),
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    )
    description = models.CharField(
        _('description'),
        max_length=80,
    )
    base_amount = models.DecimalField(
        _('base amount'),
        max_digits=15,
        decimal_places=2,
    )
    aliquot = models.DecimalField(
        _('aliquot'),
        max_digits=5,
        decimal_places=2,
    )
    amount = models.DecimalField(
        _('amount'),
        max_digits=15,
        decimal_places=2,
    )

    receipt = models.ForeignKey(
        Receipt,
        related_name='taxes',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    )

    def compute_amount(self):
        """Auto-assign and return the total amount for this tax."""
        self.amount = self.base_amount * self.aliquot / 100
        return self.amount

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('tax')
        verbose_name_plural = _('taxes')
```

This is the form and formset

```
class TaxForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tax
        fields = [
            'tax_type',
            'description',
            'base_amount',
            'aliquot',
        ]

ReceiptTaxFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    Receipt,
    Tax,
    form=TaxForm,
    extra=0,
    can_delete=False,
)
```

And this is the part of the view where i handle the formset

```
if form.is_valid() and entryFormset.is_valid() and taxFormset.is_valid():
            receipt = form.save(commit=False)
            # Tomamos el punto de venta de la sucursal y lo asignamos
            pos = request.user.userprofile.branch_office.point_of_sales
            receipt.point_of_sales = pos

            receipt.document_number = client.dni_cuit
            # Controlamos si el dni o cuit tiene 11 caracteres
            # Si los tiene asigna CUIT al típo de documento
            if len(client.dni_cuit) == 11:
                document_type = DocumentType.objects.get(id=1)
                receipt.document_type = document_type
            else:
                document_type = DocumentType.objects.get(id=10)
                receipt.document_type = document_type

            # Tomamos los valores de las lineas del comprobante
            # y generamos los totales para asentar en el comprobante
            total_amount = 0
            for f in entryFormset:
                cd = f.cleaned_data
                qty = cd.get('quantity')
                price = cd.get('unit_price')
                vat = cd.get('vat')
                subtotal = qty * price
                total_amount = total_amount + subtotal

            for t in taxFormset:
                cd = t.cleaned_data
                ba = cd.get('base_amount')
                al = cd.get('aliquot')
                ta = ba * al / 100
                total_amount = total_amount + ta

            # Asignamos el monto total a total_ammount
            # y a net_taxed para factura tipo C ya que es igual
            receipt.total_amount = total_amount
            receipt.net_taxed = total_amount

            # Asignamos 0 para Factura tipo C a los campos no necesarios
            receipt.net_untaxed = 0
            receipt.exempt_amount = 0

            # Guardamos el comprobante y las lineas del mismo
            receipt.save()
            entryFormset.save()
            taxFormset.save()
```

What i need to do is that in the taxFormset, for each tax that i get from the form, assign the amount to the object ta = ba * al / 100

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[inlineformset_factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) sits on top of modelformset_factory which uses instances

I would love to see what error it's giving you or if it's not saving but maybe you are missing on something like this.

```
        receipt.instance.total_amount = total_amount
        receipt.instance.net_taxed = total_amount

        # Asignamos 0 para Factura tipo C a los campos no necesarios
        receipt.instance.net_untaxed = 0
        receipt.instance.exempt_amount = 0

        # Guardamos el comprobante y las lineas del mismo
        receipt.save()
        entryFormset.save()
        taxFormset.save()
```

Comment: Sorry maybe I don't explain well what I need. I don't have any errors, I need to do other thing.

Like you see, I have in the model Tax the field "amount" I need to be able to set the value of amount in the view when I take all the values in the taxFormset... for each line of the tax assign the correct amount there!

Comment: I am still not sure about what you want but i will try to help with what i understand. 

- The value of amount seems to be a calculated value that will be set for each tax.

You need to loop around each form inside the formset to apply that value ?, If this is what you want to do you can loop around the formset in view or if you want also to defined a BaseModelFormSet for a formset level clean or save.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-clean-on-a-modelformset

Comment: Thanks for try to help me without understand me. i going to try to explain you with an example, when i have a form, for example a ModelForm, and in the form i don't put a mandatory attribute of the object, in the view, i use article = form.save(commit=false) and there i put artile.amount = XXXXX + XXXXX for example, for only one object this work perfect, but in a formset i have a lot of objects to save, my question is how i can assign that value to each one of the objects in the formset. (i think you can understand now what i need.

Comment: I do understand you can do them the same way you would do it with a normal form the only different is you need to loop over that formset.                   But i you can also use BaseModelFormSet where you can define it in the form.py and assign it inside your initiation of the formset like this modelformset_factory (form=yourform, formset=the_base_modelformset)   now when each form is validated now the base modelformset will be called in the end where you can do the same something like this   def clean(self): for form in self.form than assign the value you want to this form object